# What are iOS development limitations in data collection?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I know that iOS's development restrictions are harsher than those of Android, especially those concerning with privacy (ex: application usage tracking). There is allegedly only one iOS application that allows application usage tracking, which is Moment https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moment-screen-time-tracker/id771541926?mt=8 .

I'd like to know if such limitations on data collection in iOS are only imposed on the app store, or even mere iOS development.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@Jiyoun As far as my experience in iOS Development, you've more space for playing in iOS development than publishing app on Appstore. Thats why Jailbreak still exist and still in news.